# Sort object dict by not-always-there attribute

Tags: python, sorting

I want to sort an object dictionary in python. These objects have an attribute, let's call it "architecture". So, to sort my dict I do this:

```
data.sort(key=attrgetter('architecture'))
```

So far so good.

But, some objects could not have the attribute 'architecture' (sometimes yes, sometimes no) and python console raises an AttributeError exception.

So, my question is, how can I sort an object dictionary by attribute when some of the objects would not have the attribute to sort?

Comment: Could you add the sample dictionary that you are trying with?

Comment: How would you like those without the attribute to be sorted - first? Last? Excluded? You could test `hasattr` and use some default (`None`?)

Comment: use an if/else, try/except block?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to put those without the attribute last.

```
from operator import attrgetter

data_with_attr = list(d for d in data.values() if hasattr(d, 'architecture'))
data_with_attr.sort(key=itemgetter('architecture'))
data_with_attr += list(d for d in data.values() if not hasattr(d, 'architecture'))
```

I'm not sure I understand `object dictionary` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

check if the object has the attribute and use `float("inf")` or `float("-inf")` depending on where you want the object that don't have the attribute to be sorted to :

```
srt = sorted(d,key=lambda x: d[x].architecture if hasattr(d[x], "architecture") else float("inf"))
```

If you want key and value use items:

```
srt= (sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x: x[1].architecture if hasattr(x[1], "architecture") else float("inf")))
```

dicts don't have a `.sort` method

Answer (score 0):

I hate, that I cannot just comment...

How do you want to sort a dictionary? A dictionary uses hashes to access the keys, so when iterating over them, the order depends on the keys hashes and not the keys themselfes. Therefore a dictionary does  (normally) not provide sorting.

But regarding your original question (I project this on a `(key, value)`-list for now) what about this:

```
ndata = sorted((tpl for tpl in data if hasattr(tpl[0], 'architecture')),
               key=lambda x: getattr(tpl[0], 'architecture'))
# if you want to add those entries, not having 'architecture':
ndata += list(set(data) - set(ndata))
```

The question to you now is: What do you want to do with those entries, not contianing an `'architecture'`-field.